# How to create a Google calendar event with Python and Google calendar API

Tags: python, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I started with quickstart (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python) and it worked good. Then i tried to insert event with  this guide (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events). I added this code to the code from quickstart and got error. 
How should look my code to insert event in my google calendar?

So this is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools

import datetime

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/calendar-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Calendar API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'calendar-python-quickstart.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.

    Creates a Google Calendar API service object and outputs a list of the next
    10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)

    # Refer to the Python quickstart on how to setup the environment:
    # https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python
    # Change the scope to 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar' and delete any
    # stored credentials.

    event = {
      'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
      'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
      'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
      'start': {
        'dateTime': '2016-09-28T09:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
      },
      'end': {
        'dateTime': '2016-09-28T17:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
      },
      'recurrence': [
        'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
      ],
      'attendees': [
        {'email': 'lpage@example.com'},
        {'email': 'sbrin@example.com'},
      ],
      'reminders': {
        'useDefault': False,
        'overrides': [
          {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
          {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
        ],
      },
    }

    event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
    print ('Event created: %s' % (event.get('htmlLink')))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is mistake:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/demin.va/Documents/Dropbox/Programming/Google calendar API/google calendar api.py", line 96, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/demin.va/Documents/Dropbox/Programming/Google calendar API/google calendar api.py", line 92, in main
    event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
  File "C:\Users\demin.va\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\demin.va\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 838, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">
```

Comment: have you got the client_secret.json file mentioned in https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python

Comment: yes, it is in the same folder as my .py file

Comment: It should be in your home directory.

Comment: "Home" means folder where python installed?

Comment: Do a "echo ~" that is your home directory

Comment: i've put file to the **C:/Users/demin.va/** - this is my home folder. There is still same error:     File "C:\Users\demin.va\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 838, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">

Comment: Then change the line to home_dir= "C:\Users\demin.va\"

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html  home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~') will not work in windows you have to specify the folder

Comment: Thanks, It works! The problem was I didn't delete folder **.credentials** in home directory before starting program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem was in folder  ".credentials". I didn't delete it after previous starting of quickstart example with

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'
```

I just deleted this folder and program works. because now

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
```